# Ubuntu 18.10 lines around notifications

Tags: gnome-shell, 18.10

After upgrading to Ubuntu 18.10 I started getting these lines around pop up notifications:

[image: these lines]

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Is that the default shell theme? If not, what happens if you switch to the default shell theme?

Comment: You are right, this is a problem my theme https://github.com/vinceliuice/Qogir-theme/issues/17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem with the theme https://github.com/vinceliuice/Qogir-theme/issues/17